# Program copies specific lines from HTML file; certain lines break it with no visible pattern?

Tags: python, html, debugging

I have written a program in Python to take the text from specific elements in an HTML file ('input') and write it all into another document ('output'). The program works by searching for the particular HTML tag that precedes all elements of the desired type, and then writing the next line. This is the code, generalized:

```
input = open(filepath, 'r')
output = open(filepath2, 'w')
collect = 0
onstring = "string to be searched for"

for i in range(numberOfLines):
    line = input.readline()
    if onstring in line:
        collect = 1
    elif collect == 1:
        output.write(line)
        collect = 0
```

I doubt it is optimal, but it functions as intended except for one hangup: For every HTML file I try this on, between 5 and 15 of the last elements that should be copied get completely cut off. There is seemingly no pattern to what amount are cut off, so I was wondering if someone more experienced with Python could point out an apparent flaw.

If it helps, some things I have tested:

- if I append two HTML files, the same amount of posts will be cut off as are cut off from the second one alone.
- if I remove the last element that gets copied, more elements that were cut off after it are copied as normal, but usually some posts get cut off later, suggesting that the particular element that is copied is responsible for this issue. There is no discernible pattern of which ones 'break' the program, though.

Comment: Are you closing your files when your program completes?  If not, you may have writes left in the memory buffer that were never written to disk.  Try using `output.close()`

Comment: You know that html pretty much ignores line breaks, right? You might want to look at beautifulsoup to do this right.

Comment: ... also, where are you getting `numberOfLines` from?

Comment: If @James can add the answer so you can accept it, that would be great. Otherwise, put yourself a answer with the solution and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment from above.  You have opened the file for writing, but each write operation does not go directly to disk.  Instead, it is sent to a write buffer; when the buffer fills up, all of the write operation in the buffer are written to the physical disk.  Closing the file forces whatever write operations are in the buffer to be written out.

Since your program exits without closing the file, you have writes left in the memory buffer that were never written to disk. Try using:

```
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by properly closing the files with `output.close()`.

Credit goes to James for his helpful comment.

> If not, you may have writes left in the memory buffer that were never
>   written to disk. Try using `output.close()`.